# I want to write a condition where condition should paas only if variable (grp_no)contains either "full" or value between 1-64

Tags: shell-script, shell

Below is the condition:
exitprocess()
{
case $1 in
"0")
     echo "Error in connecting DB or Executing DML statements"
     exit 0
     ;;
"1")
     echo "Group number should be either FULL or between 1-64"
     exit 1
     ;;
}

TI_Validate()
{
  if [[ ${grp_no} -le "0" || ${grp_no} -ge "65" || ${grp_no} != "full" ]]
    then
    exitprocess 1 
    fi
}

## main

grp_no=$1

echo "group no is" ${grp_no}
TI_Validate

### The above condition should result to exitprocess 1 if grp_no is above 65 or grp_no is below 0 or grp_no is not "full"

### **But below is what is happening:**

./TI_Script_Wrapper1.sh full
output:
in main
group no is full
Group number should be either FULL or between 1-64

Even when I paas correct values it exits.
Can you please help me to simplify this.

Comment: 1) _Please_ read the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), especially the first item about formatting code blocks. 2) That's not the output of that script, in particular, you don't define `exitprocess` anywhere, and there's no command in the script to print those error messages. Post a complete script so that everything relevant is visible. 3) What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing a space at the end of your if statement condition...

`... ${grp_no} != "full"]]`

Should be

`... ${grp_no} != "full" ]]`

Notice the space in between `”` and `]]`.

Comment: I gave space between the two.

Comment: It is giving error message even for values full and 1-64. Can you please help on the same.

Comment: Edit your question and show your exact code, how you execute it, and the exact error.

Comment: Peschke: there is also a logical error in OP's statement: if (full OR (>=1 AND <=64) ). He's just using ORs.

Comment: ./TI_Script_Wrapper1.sh: line 25: syntax error at line 90: `AND' unexpected

Comment: i wrote   if [[ (${grp_no} -le "0" AND ${grp_no} -ge "65") OR ${grp_no} != "full" ]]

Comment: [[ (${grp_no} -le "0" && ${grp_no} -ge "65") || ${grp_no} != "full" ]] even when I write this , ---- it prints error message for correct values passed

Answer (score 0):

Does below thing solve your purpose?

```
$ grp_no=67

$ if [[ (${grp_no} -le 0 || ${grp_no} -ge 65) && ${grp_no} != "full" ]]; then echo ${grp_no}; fi

67

$ grp_no=-1

$ if [[ (${grp_no} -le 0 || ${grp_no} -ge 65) && ${grp_no} != "full" ]]; then echo ${grp_no}; fi

-1

$ grp_no="full"

$ if [[ (${grp_no} -le 0 || ${grp_no} -ge 65) && ${grp_no} != "full" ]]; then echo ${grp_no}; fi

$ grp_no=2

$ if [[ (${grp_no} -le 0 || ${grp_no} -ge 65) && ${grp_no} != "full" ]]; then echo ${grp_no}; fi
$
```

Comment: I dont want to print group no if it is more than 64.

Comment: It should print exitprocess if group no is not full or greater than 64 or less than 0

Comment: any suggestions ??

Comment: you can write your own logic in place of echo.

Comment: IT is not working only for full condition.

Comment: Hello!!  Thank You So Much .. It Works!! :) :)